# FFMPEG with Python Automation Script

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, python, plex

I am new to bash and I want to stick to Python to call bash scripts if required.

#### My setup.

1. Plex Server.
2. Google Drive Rclone.
3. Transcoding Server.

The question is related to the transcoding server.

I have started using Plex and I manually convert all my files with FFmpeg add subtitle, convert to multiple qualities and move it to Plex storage through Rclone (a team drive).

My torrent client download it to a secondary team drive then I manually download it to my server it transcode it (manually) and then store it in another team drive (Plex server remote).

Then my Plex server stream from it in multiple qualities.

#### What I want to do.

1. Download it from torrent storage. (Search for it)
2. Convert Each episode to MKV and add subtitle from subs (same name) to container.
3. MKV is then converted to various resolutions.
4. Copy files to Plex Remote.

I am very new to it but I know programming languages and I am comfortable with basic Linux.

Found a guiding script for Bash:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/574251/is-it-possible-to-convert-all-video-files-in-subdirectories-on-google-drive-usin

Answer (score 1):

I have written the code myself. Here it is.
Explaination:
Search for video in rclone remote in my case Edrive4
can run on multiple systems simultaneously as it marks a complete file which prevents other from doing same task.
automatic removal , copying, backing up, and move processed video to another directory.
url to shell script :
[Click Here](https://gist.github.com/aayush-ag/b18816001050e3de220f683ef363e70b)

In case you want to use more advanced python script that i am using,
[Click Here](https://gist.github.com/aayush-ag/b876bc9e47c03e6eaeb2d088e3dee498)

I am not explaining it as it is similar it just accepts a SUB or NOSUB parameter.
In case you want to me explain please comment.